# Tangential and radial forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

What is the tangential force and radial forces in a particle of mass m at the end of a string of length R (where G is acting downwards)?

And how to find the radial and tangential force(i.e radial force=-(T+W sin theta) and -(W cos theta) where theta is the angle between the string and the horizontal;T being the force of the string)?

Please refer to the image for further description...
[image]

Where does the formula $-T+W \sin \theta$ and $-w \cos \theta$ come from?

Comment: The tangential force $\vec r_t = \dfrac{mv^2}{r} = \dfrac{Wv^2}{gr}$ and the radial force $T$ whose expression is clearly mentioned above. What exactly is your doubt?

Comment: Where does the formula (-T+W sin theta) and (-w cos theta) come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Forces acting along the Tangential/$\hat \theta$ Direction

As can be seen in the bottom diagram, the force is the component of the $\vec W$  along the $\hat \theta$.

It's value is $W\cos\theta$ (simple trigonometry) opposite to $+\hat \theta$ so the we take the total tangential force as $-W\cos\theta$ (that's why the minus sign).

## Forces acting along the Radial/$\vec r$ Direction

### Method - 1 (Absolute(as much as it can be) Motion)

There are two forces acting along the radial direction. That's

- Tension $\vec T$ (Inwards)
- Radial component of gravitational force(Inwards) ($+W\sin\theta$) (Simple Trigonometry)

So these two forces combine together to give a centripetal acceleration(inwards)($a_{centri} = \dfrac{v^2}{r}$

Apply Newton's Second Law along the radial direction, and you can get your answer.

### Method - 2 (Relative Motion/Non-Inertial Reference Frame)

Assume you are sitting on top of the ball.
There are three forces acting along the radial direction. That's

- Tension $\vec T$ (Inwards)
- Centrifugal Force (Outwards) ($\vec F_{Centri} = m\dfrac{v^2}{r}$)
- Radial component of gravitational force ($+W\sin\theta$) (Simple Trigonometry)

Since there is no displacement/velocity along this direction, there will not be any net acceleration(i.e. the ball is in equilibrium along the radial direction).

So equate all the radial forces and you will have the answer you need.